# loess standard error as list object

Tags: r, loess

I am looking for an easy way of automatically calling the standard error of a `loess` regression as an object. I can do this with `lm` objects, but can't figure it out with `loess`, and haven't had any luck searching this and other forums.

Comment: I think @TFinch should be given a break on this one. The help file says nothing about the structure of a loess-object and you have to admit that a node with the name "s" could be one of a great many things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
foo<-loess(something)

foo$s
```

Comment: To clarify - since it's printed when you run `foo`, that means you can see what `R` does by looking at `print.loess` (or in this case, `stats:::print.loess`). You will see that it calls `x$s` in the same line as "Residual Standard Error".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The answer is obvious, but isn't in any documentation, and I suppose it's too basic to come up on any forums. I hadn't come across the triple colon operator before

Comment: No, I agree that the help page should identify every component of a `loess` object.